# Does "time played" include the time when I was browsing in-game menus?

Tags: battlefield-3

Well, there is actually nothing else to say. I like to wait for a good moment to spawn on my squad-mate and sometimes I can watch the 3rd person camera for like 3-5 minutes. Is this time affecting my SPM [score per minute]?

Comment: Maybe you should get back in the game sooner and help your team instead of leaving them down a man for 1/4 of the game.

Comment: Of course I'm exaggerating :) I can sit like that max half a minute and that happens just once-twice a day. But over time these seconds can sum to something big.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find official confirmation of this, but I believe that score per minute is based on the amount of time you're in-game, alive or dead.  You can still score points after you die, so it seems to me that score per minute would have to count the time you wait before you respawn as well as the time you are alive.

Comment: I tend not to try to change my strategy to maximize my stats though - at the end of the round, did you contribute to your team?  If so, you did a good job.  Many times the "score leaders" completely lost focus on the team objectives and were doing something that only benefited themselves.  Among my group of friends, we call that "playing a different game."

Comment: But you won't get any score points while you are dead, if you haven't had "invested" your efforts into them during the combat before getting killed, so it actually isn't logical to count "dead" time. Also, I like to work with my team on the objectives too, but, unfortunately, reciprocal teamwork is a very rare phenomenon.

Comment: Using BF3stats.com's reports engine, you can see that the 'Time' field for each player is different than the round 'Duration' field.